# r.row is not implemented in the Java driver. Use lambda syntax instead

Tags: java, rethinkdb

I want to make a query to the RethinkDB with Java. I have a table with the colums **uri** (type: `String`) and a timestamp (**timestampNextCrawl**) (type: `long`). I want to return all rows (but only the column **uri**) whose timestamp is lower than `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

The query looks like this:

```
Cursor<String> cursor = r.db("squirrel")
        .table("knownurifilter")
        .optArg("index", "uri")
        .filter(r.row("timestampNextCrawl").le(System.currentTimeMillis()))
        .g("uri")
        .run(connector.connection);
```

It gives me the following error:

```
com.rethinkdb.gen.exc.ReqlDriverError: r.row is not implemented in the Java driver. Use lambda syntax instead

at com.rethinkdb.gen.model.TopLevel.row(TopLevel.java:27)
at org.aksw.simba.squirrel.data.uri.filter.RDBKnownUriFilter.getOutdatedUris(RDBKnownUriFilter.java:57)
at org.aksw.simba.rethinkdb.UriTimeStampTests.testGetOutdatedUris(UriTimeStampTests.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues in your query:

- `optArg` is [not applicable](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/java/table/) to `table`.
- Index does not make sense here: `filter` always works over a given sequence, and you need table full-scan unless you get documents by IDs (or any other RethinkDB facilities like `between`).
- The `filter` expression cannot work because of the Java driver specifics, and it just tells you not to use `RethinkDB.r` directly. Try using `ReqlFunction1` instead.

Therefore, you have to change your query to

```
RethinkDB.r.db("squirell")
    .table("knownurifilter")
    // Java 8
    .filter(doc -> doc.getField("timestampNextCrawl").le(System.currentTimeMillis()))
    .getField("uri")
    .run(connector.connection)
```

or

```
RethinkDB.r.db("squirrel")
    .table("knownurifilter")
    // Java 7 and earlier
    .filter(new ReqlFunction1() {
        @Override
        public Object apply(final ReqlExpr doc) {
            return doc.getField("timestampNextCrawl").le(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    })
    .getField("uri")
    .run(connector.connection)
```